# Unable to fetch Web table data via Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am unable to fetch data with following program, it does not show any error but except header nothing else is fetched. Kindly guide me. This program works with other links, but not with this specific link, also I want to fetch data from all pages , without using selenium

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"}


html = requests.get(
   'https://www.nse-ebp.com/ebp/rest/placement?pub=true',
    headers=headers).content


df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]

print(df)
```

Comment: I get access denied. Also, please don't abuse tags.

Comment: Also, you don't need `requests` if you are going to use `pandas.read_html`.

Comment: Access denied for what ?, I am able to access website

Comment: Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.nse-ebp.com/" on this server.

Reference #18.15131002.1631604538.6e1ac301 That is when I open the link in the browser

Comment: Maybe its only available in India , locked for other countries, maybe person from other country will need to change server via VPN addon on browser

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is generated dynamically with JavaScript, so you won't get it with `bs4` as it's simply not in the source HTML.

However, there's an endpoint you can query that returns all the data that's used to populate the table.

Here's how:

```py
import json

import requests

endpoint = "https://www.nse-ebp.com/ebp/rest/placement/all"

headers = {
    "pageToken": "f06c7498-ac12-4def-95d2-f0fb903fff64",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
payload = {
    "columnNames": [
        "id", "biddingDate", "issuerName", "displayIsin", "description",
        "allotmentDate", "faceValue", "amountRaised", "displayMaturityDate",
        "coupon", "yield", "displayCreditRatings", "bookOpen", "placementType",
        "fixedBid", "allocMethod", "settMethod", "countQib", "countNonQib",
    ]
}

response = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    1,
    null,
    "Aditya Birla Finance Limited",
    "INE860H07EA3",
    "7.6630% SECURED REDEEMABLE NON CONVERTIBLE DEBENTURES. SERIES ABFL NCD H1 FY 2016-17. DATE OF MATURITY 18/05/2018",
    "23-11-2016",
    1000000.0,
    150.0,
    "18-05-2018",
    7.663,
    null,
    "ICRA-AA+, FITCH-AA+",
    null,
    "New Issue",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    1,
    0
  ],
and much more ...
```

EDIT: Here's how to dump it to a `.csv` file.

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests

endpoint = "https://www.nse-ebp.com/ebp/rest/placement/all"

headers = {
    "pageToken": "f06c7498-ac12-4def-95d2-f0fb903fff64",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
payload = {
    "columnNames": [
        "id", "biddingDate", "issuerName", "displayIsin", "description",
        "allotmentDate", "faceValue", "amountRaised", "displayMaturityDate",
        "coupon", "yield", "displayCreditRatings", "bookOpen", "placementType",
        "fixedBid", "allocMethod", "settMethod", "countQib", "countNonQib",
    ]
}

response = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json(), columns=payload["columnNames"])
df.to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False)
```